# Optimization of a function over a geometric region

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

Say I have a function `f[x,y,z]`, what is a good way to find its minimum or maximum value over a continuous region (e.g. a `ConvexHullMesh`)? Currently, I generate random points in said region and find their optimal value of `f`. But it's very inefficient, though the accuracy does increase with more points.

Comment: "Currently, I generate random points in said region and find their optimal value of `f`." - you would probably be amused to know that the `"RandomSearch"` setting for the `Method` option of `NMinimize[]`/`NMaximize[]` does exactly that, except perhaps a bit more systematically than you.

Comment: @J.M. I am dumb, but thankful.hahua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize)/[`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize). Here is a sample convex hull mesh:

```
SeedRandom[1];
mesh = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[10, {20,3}]]
```

[image]

And here is a function:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Sin[x y z] x y z
```

And here are the minimum/maximum of `f` over `mesh`:

```
Minimize[f[x, y, z], {x,y,z} ∈ mesh]
Maximize[f[x, y, z], {x,y,z} ∈ mesh]
```

> {-237.192, {x -> 6.31328, y -> 7.5132, z -> 5.00063}}
>
> {221.485, {x -> 7.89306, y -> 6.12804, z -> 4.57911}}